# Problema al subir archivo a Google Drive con su API con Python

Tags: python, script, google-drive

Estoy intentando subir un archivo a Google Drive usando su API para Python ya que necesito hacer un script para subir copias de seguridad automáticas desde mi servidor a Google Drive si interacción de usuario. tengo el siguiente código el cual he extraído de la documentación de Google Drive.

Código de mi Script:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

file_metadata = {
  'name' : 'report.csv',
  'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/report.csv',
                        mimetype='text/csv',
                        resumable=True)
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print ("File ID: %s" % file.get("id"))
main()
```

Los errores que me muestra son estos:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gdriveprueba.py", line 55, in <module>
    resumable=True)
  File "/home/servicioweb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/servicioweb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 554, in __init__
    fd = open(self._filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files/report.csv'
```

El directorio files lo cree manualmente en Google Drive pero me sigue diciendo que no lo encuentra, que puede estar pasando que no logro ver?

Comment: Además que no encuentra el archivo en la ruta otro problema que tiene el código es que estás un * scope* insuficiente : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly' sólo permite leer los metadatos y tu lo que quieres hacer es subir un archivo.

Comment: Un detalle menor (irrelevante para lo que preguntas). A menos que estés usando python 2.7 (y no deberías, está obsoleto), puedes eliminar el `from __future__ import print_function`.

Answer (score 0):

El error que devuelve es conciso, no encuentra el fichero `report.csv`.

```
media = MediaFileUpload('files/report.csv',
                    mimetype='text/csv',
                    resumable=True)
```

Fíjate bien en la ruta `files/report.csv` y comprueba que el archivo que deseas subir se encuentra ahí en tu PC/servidor. Esa ruta que has indicado es relativa, debes de tener una carpeta files al mismo nivel que tu script para que pueda acceder a `report.csv`.